# Converting command cURL to PHP - Stuck with passing POSTFIELD data

Tags: php, curl

In an attempt to replicate the following cURL:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX' 'https://XXXXXXXXX.XXX.com/api/v3/assets/76c860cd184ae4adfa105d46135c9b27.json' -F 'name=fileupdate99.pdf' -F 'description=curlviaphp'
```

The purpose of the call is to update the two fields (name & description) at this specific end point.

I used https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ to get the bulk of the conversion. However, I appear to be stuck on passing the data. 
From what I can tell, it looks like the -F flag is expected (also used to upload files) and I can't make a swap to -d (I tried running call in the command line and -d wasn't accepted).

```
<?php

$subdomain = "XXXXXXXX";
$name = "fileupdate4.pdf";
$description = "curlviaphp";
$auth = "XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX";
$asset = "76c860cd184ae4adfa105d46135c9b27";


$ch = curl_init();

$curlurl = "https://" . $subdomain . ".XXX.com/api/v3/assets/" . $asset . ".json' ";

$variables = array(
    "name" =>  $name,
    "description" => $description,
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $variables);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $auth;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo "Error:" . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

When I execute, the code runs and I get a blank page (no return and no change on the receiving end).
What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using `multipart/form-data`? That's generally only needed when you're uploading a file.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to set that header explicitly. Whenever `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is an array, it will automatically use `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Are you sure the original code is `name=fileupdate99.pdf` and not `name=@fileupdate99.pdf`? The `@` means that it should upload the contents of the file.

Comment: I’m using multipart/form-data because a further expansion of this call will include uploading a file. The ‘name’ variable is a label field to rename an existing file

Comment: I can't see any reason why this shouldn't work. The only difference between `-d` and `-F` is whether they use url-encoded or form-data format, and PHP curl automatically uses form-data when `$variables` is an array. Try doing a packet capture to see what's actually being sent and compare it with the CLI.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - After re-reading everything, there is an empty space at the ebd of the $curlurl variable that CURLOPT_URL didn't know what to do with

Comment: The problem is more likely to be the single quote after `.json`.